# Select by month

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dateframe with a date field called `datum`

```
df['datum'].iloc[0]
Out[58]: datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 2, 2, 0, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=120, name=None))

type(df['datum'].iloc[0])
Out[59]: datetime.datetime
```

I want to select rows with a month <= 6:

```
df.loc[df['datum'].dt.month <= 6]
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

But all rows are datetimes?

```
df['datum'] = df['datum'].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='raise')
```

no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are object datetimes, so for converting to Timestamps need:

```
print (df['datum'].dtype)
object

df['datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datum'], utc=True)

df.loc[df['datum'].dt.month <= 6]
```